# How to insert multiple records with some conditions

Tags: mysql, performance, stored-procedures

I have two tables. One table contains words. Other table contains points.

```
table words:

id word


table points:

id wordid x y
```

word column is unique.

i want to write stored procedure which takes on input current x value and list of word|y values.

For example:

It's initial words table rows:

```
id word
1  Carrot
2  Apple
3  Potato
```

We call procedure   `StoreData(x = 5, words = { Carrot:123, Onion:321 })`.

As a result we have:

```
Words table:

  id word
  1  Carrot
  2  Apple
  3  Potato
  4  Onion 


Points table:    
id wordid x  y 
1    1    5 123 
2    4    5 321
```

How to do it?

Comment: Your question could use a better title. "How to do this query" is general enough to be the title of a 1/4 of the questions on stack overflow. :-)

Comment: @Randy Ofcourse i know straignforward way with multiple queries but it works very slow. Donnt write code. Just give me a few tips where i can found examples. I am very new to mysql that's why it's hard to me write such procedure.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't pass structured data as a parameter to a stored procedure: you would have to first insert it into a (temporary) table somewhere, then read the contents of that table from within your procedure.  As such, you may as well just insert directly into your destination tables:

```
INSERT IGNORE INTO Words (word) VALUES ('Carrot'), ('Onion');

INSERT INTO Points (wordid, x, y)
  SELECT Words.id, 5, y
  FROM   Words NATURAL JOIN (
      SELECT 'Carrot' AS word, 123 AS y
    UNION ALL
      SELECT 'Onion'  AS word, 321 AS y
  ) AS t;
```

See it on [sqlfiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/a1bd7/1/0).

(Incidentally, my materialised table `t` is essentially the table you'd have to create and populate before calling your stored procedure):

```
DELIMITER ;;
CREATE PROCEDURE StoreData(IN x INT) BEGIN
  INSERT IGNORE INTO Words SELECT word FROM args;
  INSERT IGNORE INTO Points (wordid, x, y)
    SELECT Words.id, 5, y FROM Words NATURAL JOIN args;
END;;
DELIMITER ;

DROP   TEMPORARY TABLE IF EXISTS args;
CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE args (word VARCHAR(20), y INT);
INSERT INTO args VALUES ('Carrot', 123), ('Onion', 321);
CALL StoreData(5);
```

Comment: I need to store a few thousand words per second. Is it solution enought fast?